# Progress bar with image

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I am trying to make a progress bar with 2 images. One of them is grey and the other picture is green. When I click the button, I want to progress it, but it is not working.

Here is the my code (`progressGreen` and `progressGrey` are `UIImageView`s):

```
- (IBAction)nextButton:(id)sender {
  self.progressGreen.tag = rowNumber; // I am giving a number
  [self progess];
}

-(void) progess {   
  CGRect rect = self.progressGrey.frame;
  rect.size.width = (rect.size.width * (self.progressGreen.tag)) / questions.count;
  self.progressGreen.frame = rect;
}
```

[image: This is my screenshot.]

What is my mistake?

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: when i click the next button , it is not progressing

Comment: Are you using a `UIProgressView` or just two images?

Comment: No,i don't use UIProgressView,i am using 2 images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `progressImage` and `trackImage` properties on `UIProgressView`. This will be much easier than doing it manually.

Comment: Ok, i am going to try it.